# function with arrays no works well

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have problem with function , if i use the script and no works as function works fine , but if use it as function no works me and no show the values right , for example with the function show me only 1 value and if don´t use as function show me all values right , i don´t know if the problem it´s with arrays inside function or what

```
<?php

function update($array_1)
{

$val=explode(","$array_1);


foreach ($val as $key=>$value) 
{   
$values_db[]="".$key."";
}

foreach($_POST['opt'] as $key2=>$value2)
{
$values_post[]="".$key2."";
}

$aa=array_diff($values_db,$values_post);
$bb=array_intersect($values_db,$values_post);

foreach($aa as $aaa)
{
print "<b>".$aaa." ".$opt[$aaa]."</b><br>";
}

foreach($bb as $bbb)
{   
print "".$bbb." ".$_POST['opt'][$bbb]."<br>";   
}


}

update("val1,val2");

?>
```

The problem it´s if use as function only , i think if howewer the values i send by POST in function no works fine and if use the script as no function receive ok

Regards

Comment: Typo? => `$val=explode(",",$aaray_1);` might have meant to use `$val=explode(",",$array_1);` ?

Comment: I writte here error mine , but the most improtant why works outside funcrion and no inside function the script

Comment: I put right now , regards

Comment: Well have you done any debugging at all?  Where does the performance of the function vary from what you expect?

Comment: Yes , for example if i use as simple script no function , when i send values from post show the common values and no common perfect , when use in function only show me one value and the others values no show me , the script works fine single but inside function no works fine , regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first assumption is that when you put your code into a function, the variables you are accessing are no longer available inside the function's [scope](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) (`$values_db` and `$values_post`). You've also referenced `$opt[$aaa]` and I can't see where you're defining `$opt`. This might be another variable that you are using outside the function and when you wrap your code into a function it is no longer available.

In your case, the quickest solution would be to declare these variables as global so that you can access them as you normally would inside the function:

```
function update($array_1) {
    global $values_db, $values_post, $opt;
    // ...
}
```

Other options are that you could use internal variables inside the function and [return](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) the values from the function, adding them to your array outside the function:

```
function update($array_1) {
    $values_db = array();
    $values_db[] = 'world!';
    return $values_db; 
}

$values_db = array('Hello ');
$values_db = array_merge($values_db, update($your_other_array)); // ['Hello ', 'world!']
```

Your third option is to [pass those variables by reference](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.references.pass.php) so that they can be updated in the global scope from within the function:

```
function update($array_1, &$values_db, &$values_post, &$opt) {
    // ...
}

update("val1,val2", $values_db, $values_post, $opt);
```